# Group or Ring Structure on the set of Topologies over a finite Set

Tags: general-topology, group-theory

Let $X=\{1,\ldots,n\}$ and let $T$ be the topologies on $X$. Is there a known (set theoretic) group or even ring structure on $T$? I thought about the operations of a ring of sets (symmetric difference and intersection) but was not able to prove/disprove. (Of course you can always define e.g. a cyclic group on $T$ but I am wondering whether there is something that makes use of the properies of the topologies.)

Comment: The symmetric difference of two topologies is no topology as it will neither contain $X$ nor $\emptyset$, so the usual operations of a ring of sets will not work.

Comment: Oh right thanks! Now I wonder how I could have missed that...=)

Comment: @Matthias: It's not a topology, but it generates a unique topology.

Comment: The intersection of two topologies is a topology, so maybe that could be the multiplication.  But what the addition would be, I cannot say at this point. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @AsafKaragila : So you're suggesting we consider the topology generated by the symmetric difference of two topologies as something that might serve as their sum? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @Michael: Probably not, because I don't think that you can identify the inverse like that, or that it will be unique.

Comment: Might there be some theorem that says there's no ring structure that is in some reasonable sense compatible with the topological structure?

Comment: Well, for what it's worth, topologies on a set make a complete lattice. So perhaps one can start by looking at groups or rings that have lattice structure on them.

Comment: Are you looking at distinct topologies or inequivalent topologies? i.e. are you counting $\{\emptyset,\{1\},\{1,2\}\}$ and $\{\emptyset,\{2\},\{1,2\}\}$ as the same topology?

Comment: Either way, for small values of $n$ the number of topologies on an $n$ element set(sequences https://oeis.org/A000798 and https://oeis.org/A001930) contain quite a few prime numbers and not many 'nicely factorizable' numbers. I doubt that there is a group of  order $35979$ which acts naturally on the set of topologies on $\{1...8\}$.